# How to set up google payment or Google Checkout for donate some amount in android app?

Tags: android

I want to set up donate in my app.can you please suggest me how to setup google checkout/wallet or any other service from google only.i have set up in-app purchase but its not provide dymanic amount to pay.

thanks in advance.